# What is the scope of a variable in the main function of C++?

Tags: c++

Say I have the main function in C++ with a vector declared:

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> arr (10, 5);

  for (auto num : arr)
  {
    cout << num << endl;
  }
}
```

From my understanding of scope, the variable is accessible anywhere from where it was defined, down to the closing bracket of the environment it was defined in. So here, arr is accessible anywhere in main(), and thus it is in the scope of the for loop.

However, now say I define a function and call the function in main.

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> arr (10, 5);
  func();
}

void func()
{
  arr.push_back(1);
}
```

Now, arr is undefined within func(). I understand why this is the case, since strictly speaking, array is not defined anywhere within func()'s scope. I realize we have to pass arr as a parameter to func() in order for this to work. But this conflicts with my understanding of scope as defined above, where arr is accessible anywhere within main, and since func() is called in main, why does it not have access to arr?

Extra: I've been developing in JS for awhile now, so I've gotten used to this pattern of nested functions:

```
function main() {
  let a = 5;
  function nested() {
    console.log(a)
  }
}
```

And here, a is accessible in the nested function.

Comment: *"Now, arr is undefined within func()"* - yes, end of story. No it does not magically get defined just because you call it from somewhere where `arr` exists. And the javascript snippet is irrelevant because it uses a completely different language feature, a nested function, not a called / invoked function.

Comment: What you see is exactly what scope is. arr is known in main and is known when you call func, but not in func itself. Which is why you have to pass it as argument to func as you suggested yourself.

Comment: C++ has a similar construct: `auto nested = [&] { std::cout << a; };`. As you can see, it's not the same thing as a function call, just like how JS's nested functions aren't the same as JS function calls.

Comment: _"...since func() is called in main..."_ - but `func` does not exist in main so can not see the names defined in main.

Comment: In Javascript, if you call a function in `main`, then `main`'s variables are not implicitly available in that function either. If you want a closure, use a closure.

Comment: concerning then nesting you could use a global variable, that would achieve the same thing, but don't go that way, it is bad practice. javascript is not a compiled language and is different from c++ in all respects. Don't compare apples with pears.

Comment: LOL there is many answers to this question.

Comment: @CEPB LOL2 full rules for unqualified name look up https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks for the link!!! But this question: `why I cannot access variable x`, where x is in main and they access it in `foo()` is so common here that its funny!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In c++ visibility of variable is inside `{}` where it is declared. It is possible to make global variable, but you need to declare it at top of file. If you want to write body function you need to tell firstly that function will exists.

```
void func();
vector<int> arr (10, 5);
int main()
{
  func();
}

void func()
{
  arr.push_back(1);
}
```

Edit:

But it's a bad practice, recommended it's using a reference.

```
void func(vector<int> &arr);

int main()
{
  vector<int> arr (10, 5);
  func(arr);
}

void func(vector<int> &arr)
{
  arr.push_back(1);
}
```

Comment: Auch, just learned the other day, do not do this in C++ it's bad practice!!!! Read this: https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/tag/pitfall/RSPEC-5421

Comment: @CEPB yes you right, but I think for beginner its easier to make globally and learn basics, than used pointers since maybe first day of code

Comment: +1, I hope you do not mind me editing your answer. Pointer parameter is `foo (int *a)` where reference is `foo (int &a)`. Basic difference between them is that you can change address of `*a` not `&a`.